# How do I use the Hand Tool as default in Adobe Reader?

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

I would like to use the *Hand* Tool as default for all documents in Adobe Reader on Windows.

Currently it opens with the *Select* Tool. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: 9.3.1 keeps defaulting to the 'select' tool for me, no matter what I do. It's driving me nuts. I would downgrade if I could just for this purpose, but don't have the rights on my work computer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the Hand Tool from menu (Tools / Select and Zoom), Adobe Reader should keep this setting when you open other documents later (tested with Adobe Reader 9).

Comment: I confirm that this still works in Adobe Reader 10.

Comment: there's not tools menu in Reader 10.

Comment: There's no tool menu in Reader 10 - confirmed

Answer (score 7):

On **Windows**, the relevant preference is set in the *registry* like this: -

- Open the Registry Editor -->

`regedit.exe`

- Browse to the relevant key -->

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\[version]\Selection`

- Edit the appropriate value -->

Change the data of `aDefaultSelect` to *Hand*.

**PS**: I could not make this work for previously opened documents until I restored the **default settings** for *Adobe Reader* by deleting the following key -->

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\[version]\`

You might not have to take this step.

Comment: With the latest version they seem to have moved everything to the `Adobe Acrobat` key (even for Reader): `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\[version]\ ... `

Comment: YES, @InteXX this is the only solution that worked for me on Windows 11 with the latest Acrobat DC update 2022-11-27

Answer (score 5):

There is no Tools menu on my version, nor is there any Hand tool under Zoom.

I found the Hand with a **right click on the page**.

Unfortunately, from the next right-click, I also accidentally hid the toolbars and now I can't find any way of getting them back.

Answer (score 2):

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2021. The most common method is through Preferences/Accessories/"Uncheck" box saying, "Always display keyboard selection cursor."

This box was already unchecked for me so this is obviously the wrong route for me. I found that if I Right-click my mouse and literally click "Hand Tool", then exit Adobe and reopen it, it now starts with my Hand Tool.

Such a strange random way to make something a 'Default', but that's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe Reader DC the default tool is configured in <kbd>Edit</kbd>/<kbd>Preferences...</kbd>/<kbd>General</kbd> ([credits](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/select-tool-hand-tool-changing-default-preferences/td-p/2534984?page=1)):

- Touch Mode **Never** = Selection Tool is default
- Touch Mode **Auto-Detect** = Hand Tool is default

If you enable **Use single-key accelerators to access tools**, the mode can be toggled *while* pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Now it would be super useful if one could bind this toggle e.g. to a [HP Tilt Pens' B-Button](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Tilt-Pen-Configuration-Right-Clicking/m-p/6826178/highlight/true#M180376), but I did not yet sort out whether this is possible.

Comment: Touch Mode - Always fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

splattne's solution doesn't work for me, Adobe Reader always switches back to the Select Tool on startup. Following the hints in [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/395585) on adobe.com, I found that the following works on Unix:

– Open `~/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Preferences/reader_prefs` in a text editor.

– Search for the section beginning with `/Selection [/c <<` and ending with `>>]`.

– Replace the whole section with

```
/Selection [/c <<   /DefaultSelect [/a /Hand]
>>]
```

It should also work on other platforms if the corresponding preferences file can be located.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just right click on any part of the document.
2. In the menu select "Hand Tool"
3. Done

Answer (score 0):

Hand tool and selection tool is related to touch mode settings.

When the program detects that the user is using a touch screen then it selects hand tool. so that your hand can be used as usual way.
But when it detects that , there is no touch-input / touchscreen connected then it selects selection tool (cursor) for using with mouse.

So you need to set touch mode option to >Always. Thus the program will always presume that the user is in touch mode. And give you the hand tool as default.

**To make hand tool default ,
Go to : Edit > Preferences > General >Touch Mode > Always**

[image: touch mode option acrobat reader]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences - > Accessibility, uncheck the box "Always display the keybord selection cursor"

Answer (score 0):

the only working solution at this moment is to change option "aDefaultSelect" to "Hand" in registry editor in the branch HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\Selection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).